# Setting roles on charts with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am writing a code in spread sheet app script.

I am trying to create a ColumnTable and make annotations or color different columns.

Google's Visualization is very clear about it, but there very little documentation on using it with app script.

the code i want to execute is is similiar to:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation'}],
     ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', 'Cu' ],
     ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', 'Ag' ],
     ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold', 'Au' ],
     ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', 'Pt' ]
  ]);
```

But I can't execute the **['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' }** line, because there is no Charts.ColumnType like 'role'.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [setColumns(columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder#setColumns(Object)) as it also makes a reference to [Visualization Chart's DataTable Roles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder#setColumns(Object))

> **setColumns(columns)**
>
> Sets the indexes of the columns to include in the data view as well as
>   specifying role-column information. This subset of column indexes
>   refer to the columns of the data source that the data view will be
>   derived from.
>
> A column role describes the purpose of the data in that column: for
>   example, a column might hold data describing tooltip text, data point
>   annotations, or uncertainty indicators. For more details, see
>   DataTable Roles in the Google Charts documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];

  var COLUMN_SPEC = [
  0, // H
  1, //

  {sourceColumn: 1, role: 'annotation'},
    2, //
    {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'annotation'}
];

  var viewSpec = Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
      .setColumns(COLUMN_SPEC)
      .build();

  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'H')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Test1')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Test2')
      .addRow(['H1 18', 13, 33])
      .addRow(['H2 18', 10, 25])
      .addRow(['H1 19', 17, 23])
      .addRow(['H2 19', 17, 29])
      .build();

  var chartBuilder = Charts.newLineChart()
      .setXAxisTitle('H')
      .setYAxisTitle('Value')
      .setDimensions(600, 500)
  .setDataViewDefinition(viewSpec)
      //.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
      .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.NORMAL)
      .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.NONE)
      .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM)
      .setDataTable(data);

  var chart = chartBuilder.build();  

  var areaBlob = chart.getBlob().getAs('image/png').setName("areaBlob");
  slide.insertImage(areaBlob,  3, 3, 306, 163);  
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some information about how you think this is of help to the question asker.